# scope raising MysQL error : Illegal mix of collations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Very weird : 
I have a scope running fine :

```
scope :starting_at, lambda {|start_date|
    where("CAST(starts_at AS TIME) = ?", Event.db_time(start_date))
}

(rdb:1) sd1 => 2012-12-16 10:00:00 +0100
Event.starting_at(sd1)
[#<Event id: 1, account_id: 1, place_id: 1, slug: "my-new-....
```

I have another similar scope , which raises an error :

```
scope :starting_at_between, lambda {|start_time, end_time|
    where( "? <= CAST(starts_at AS TIME) <= ?", Event.db_time(start_time), Event.db_time(end_time) )
}
(rdb:1) sd2  =>  2012-12-15 08:00:00 +0100
(rdb:1) ed2  =>  2012-12-19 23:00:00 +0100
Event.starting_at_between(ed2, sd2)
INTERNAL ERROR!!! Mysql2::Error: Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '<=': SELECT `events`.* FROM `events`  WHERE ('23:00:00' <= CAST(starts_at AS TIME) <= '08:00:00')
```

what's wrong using this one ...?
not because of 2 paramaters ..
I have a similar scope in which the CAST is AS DATE and it's running fine ...

```
scope :starting_on_between, lambda { |start_date, end_date|
    where( "? <= CAST(starts_at AS DATE) <= ?", Event.db_date(start_date), Event.db_date(end_date) )
}
Event.starting_on_between(ed2, sd2)
[#<Event id: 1, account_id: 1, place_id: 1, slug:...
```

Comment: ... https://www.google.ca/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=Illegal+mix+of+collations+(utf8_general_ci%2CCOERCIBLE)+and+(latin1_swedish_ci%2CNUMERIC)&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&redir_esc=&ei=moy_UOPFJuPb0QHW_YD4BQ ctrl+C ctrl+V on Google. It helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong CAST ..  should be done on the filter values ... not on the db record attribute ..

scope :starting_at_between, lambda {|start_time, end_time|
    where( "CAST( ? AS TIME) <= starts_at <= CAST( ? AS TIME)", Event.db_time(start_time), Event.db_time(end_time) )
  }

Comment: better using BETWEEN...
where( "CAST( starts_at AS TIME) BETWEEN ? AND ?, Event.db_time(start_time), Event.db_time(end_time) )